# Iterating over two lists using Java 8 streams

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

How can I write the following in Java 8 streams?

```
int total = 0;
  for (ObjectA obja : rootObj.getListA()) {
    for (ObjectB objb : obja.getListB()) {
        total += objb.getCount() * obja.getCount();
    }
   }

return total;
```

Answer (score 5):

The canonical solution for converting nested `for` loops to `Stream` API usage is via `flatMap`:

```
return rootObj.getListA().stream()
.flatMapToInt(objA->objA.getListB().stream()
                                   .mapToInt(objB->objB.getCount() * objA.getCount()))
.sum();
```

This allows you to perform an operation for each inner iteration. However, in the special case of summing you may simplify the operation as it doesn’t matter whether you compute `(a+b+c+d)` or `(a+b)+(c+d)`:

```
return rootObj.getListA().stream()
.mapToInt(objA->objA.getListB().stream()
                               .mapToInt(objB->objB.getCount() * objA.getCount()).sum())
.sum();
```

And when we are at remembering elementary arithmetics we should also recall that `(a*x)+(b*x)` is equal to `(a+b)*x`, in other words, there is no need to multiply every item of `ListB` with the count of `objA` as we can also just multiple the resulting sum with that count:

```
return rootObj.getListA().stream()
.mapToInt(objA->objA.getListB().stream().mapToInt(ObjectB::getCount).sum()*objA.getCount())
.sum();
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative solution which might be preferable in a number of cases:

```
int total = rootObj.getListA().stream()
    .flatMapToInt(objA -> objA.getListB()
         .stream().mapToInt(objB -> objB.getCount() * objA.getCount()))
    .sum();
```

Comment: what is the difference of using flatMapToInt insdead of mapToInt?

Comment: `mapToInt` transforms every element to another, while `flatMapToInt` transforms single element to the sequence of several elements.

Answer (score 2):

Fairly easy : map `ObjectA` to the sum of all its `ObjectB::getCount` multiplied by its own `getCount()`, then simply sum the `IntStream` :

```
int total = rootObj.getListA().stream()
    .mapToInt(obja -> obja.getCount() * obja.getListB().stream().mapToInt(ObjectB::getCount).sum())
    .sum();
```

To improve readability you can introduce a private helper method :

```
int total = rootObj.getListA().stream()
    .mapToInt(this::calculate)
    .sum();
```

with helper method :

```
private int calculate(ObjectA obja) {
    return obja.getListB().stream()
            .mapToInt(ObjectB::getCount)
            .sum() * obja.getCount();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

And for the more general solution of walking two streams at once there's this *not-very-nice but it works* solution.

```
public static <A, B, C> Stream<C> zip(
        Stream<A> a,
        Stream<B> b,
        BiFunction<A, B, C> op) {
    Iterator<A> i1 = a.iterator();
    Iterator<B> i2 = b.iterator();
    Iterable<C> i = () -> new Iterator<C>() {
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return i1.hasNext() && i2.hasNext();
        }

        @Override
        public C next() {
            return op.apply(i1.next(), i2.next());
        }

    };
    // Not certain whether we can do this in parallel - probably not.
    return StreamSupport.stream(i.spliterator(), false);
}
```

Comment: That's not what the OP wants. You are iterating two streams synchronously and author wants to iterate all the values of listB list for every value of listA. Your version is "dot product" while OP wants a "cross product".

Comment: @TagirValeev - That is true - but this answer applies to the question title *Iterating over two lists using Java 8 streams*.