# Is it possible to get two result and join them with stream in JAVA8?

Tags: java, java-8

I want to get the name and the and the URL from Remote

```
public interface Remote {
    String getName();

    Remote withName(String name);

    String getUrl();

    Remote withUrl(String url);
}

   List<String> remoteNames = remoteList.stream().map(Remote::getName).filter(name -> name.equalsIgnoreCase(origin)).collect(Collectors.toList());

   List<String> remoteUrls = remoteList.stream().map(Remote::GetUrl).filter(url-> url.equalsIgnoreCase(origin)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is it possible to do it in one call and to get all the result in one variable ?

Comment: You mean remote names and remote urls in one List? Won't it cause problems to read?

Comment: "one variable"? a little too vague? do you want a list of strings where the string is `name + url` or do you want a `Map<String,String>` or a list of maps or an object which has fields name and url or list of such objects? also, there might be a typo in the second stream `Remote::GetUrl`, capital 'G', code wouldn't compile because it wouldn't find `GetUrl`.

Comment: Does it the right way to get two members . can I do it in better way or is it the way to do it ? there is no connection between the name and the URL

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to get a list of tuples containing a pair of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new class that hold both fields and create it at `map` time:

```
List<NameAndURL> remotes = remoteList.stream().map(t -> new NameAndURL(t.getName(), t.getURL()))...
```

Alternately you can [zip the two streams together](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30368479/823393).

Comment: Yeah, and then, to get a specific name or URL you can invoke `remotes.get(index).getName()` resp. `remotes.get(index).getUrl()` , just like you can do on the original `List<Remote>`…